# How to make dynamic multiple self joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

For simplification let's assume we have a table for students who finished some classes on specific time. given that some students may have complete time *null* for some classes which they have enrolled but not yet finish.

| student_id | name | course_name | complete_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Noah | Database_L2 | NULL |
| 1 | Noah | Math_L1 | 2021-02-01 |
| 2 | Luke | Database_L2 | 2021-10-8 |
| 2 | Luke | Database_L1 | 2021-06-06 |
| 2 | Luke | Math_L1 | 2021-03-15 |
| 2 | Luke | Physics_L1 | NULL |
| 1 | Noah | Database_L1 | 2021-08-30 |

The query is to find the names of students who finished a given class sequence.
For example for given sequence:

- (Math_L1, Database_L1) 2 students finished that sequence (Noah & Luke).
- for (Math_L1, Database_L1, Database_L2) only 1 student (Luke).

How can this be done in single query given any sequence?

Edit :

- For simplicity, we can assume fixed sequence length of 3

Comment: For simplicity, can it be assumed that the sequence can be hard-coded/have fixed length?

Comment: sure. let's assume sequence length to be 3

Comment: You are supposed to show your own efforts here and tell us where you got stuck. In this example you could have shown your query with a self join (which you already mention in your title) for two classes and then tell us that you don't know how to extend this for a variable number of classes. Please show your efforts next time. As is, self-joins are not the solution, because you'd have to add a join for every class, so a fixed query could only work for a fixed number of classes as user202729 suggested. If you want this for a dynamic number of classes, you need another approach. (See my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have this dynamic, i.e. a fixed query that works for any number of courses, you could work with aggregation and a string holding the comma-separated classes. For this to work, this string must be in a fixed format, i.e. classes must be ordered alphabetically and separated by a comma (and no additional blank).

```
set @courses = 'Database_L1,Math_L1';

select name
from mytable
where find_in_set(course_name, @courses)
and complete_time <= now()
group by name
having group_concat(course_name order by course_name) = @courses
order by name;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=45f43faf9fed09e79998717e9723d5df

As you see, there is no self join needed. We just aggregate by name and see if when looking for the requested classes, we end up with the same class list string as requested (i.e. all those classes are in the string).

My query excludes Noah from the result by the way, because the completion day (2021-08-30) is in the future. If you want to consider future dates as completed (if these can even occur in your real database), then change the `WHERE` clause accordingly (e.g. to `complete_time is not null`).